# Committing first page of sparse texture crashes at glfwDestroyWindow

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, glad

The following OpenGL/GLFW/GLAD code (MCVE version) crashes the process with the following access violation exception in nvoglv64.dll:

```
0x00007FFC731F586F (nvoglv64.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0x0000000000024AA8.
```

at the `glfwDestroyWindow(window)` call at the end of the code listing below, and I don't know, why. This call won't crash when either not calling `glTexPageCommitmentARB` or calling it with a `commit` of `GL_FALSE/0`.

I've read the specification of [ARB_sparse_texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture.txt) three times now, checking the conditions of *every* argument of `glTexPageCommitmentARB` (x, y, z, width, height, depth multiples of the page sizes of the internal format) and I am somewhat sure that I've followed all instructions on how to use that function correctly. I've also checked for any OpenGL errors with a debug context and a debug message callback before, there were no outputs.

Further information:

- OS: Windows 10 x64 (20H2)
- Driver: Nvidia 461.09 (DCH)
- GLAD Configuration: OpenGL 4.3 Core + ARB_sparse_texture + ARB_sparse_texture2
- GLFW: Fresh local MSVC x64 Release build from Git commit [0b9e48fa3df9c18](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/0b9e48fa3df9c184ff1abfb2452fd1a4b696ecd8)

The fprintf right before the `glTexPageCommitmentARB` call in the code below print the following output before the crash at the end of the program:

```
256 128 1 32768
```

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "GLFW window NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "gladLoadGLLoader failed");
        exit(2);
    }
    if (!GLAD_GL_ARB_sparse_texture || !GLAD_GL_ARB_sparse_texture2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "GL_ARB_sparse_texture or GL_ARB_sparse_texture2 unsupported");
        exit(3);
    }
    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    // activate sparse allocation for this texture
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SPARSE_ARB, GL_TRUE);
    // use default page size index 0 (as per ARB_sparse_texture2)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VIRTUAL_PAGE_SIZE_INDEX_ARB, 0);
    GLint width, height, depth, maxSparseTexSize;
    // query page size for width, height and depth
    // R16UI is supported as sparse texture internal format as per
    // https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sparse_texture.txt
    glGetInternalformativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_R16UI, GL_VIRTUAL_PAGE_SIZE_X_ARB, 1, &width);
    glGetInternalformativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_R16UI, GL_VIRTUAL_PAGE_SIZE_Y_ARB, 1, &height);
    glGetInternalformativ(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_R16UI, GL_VIRTUAL_PAGE_SIZE_Z_ARB, 1, &depth);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_SPARSE_TEXTURE_SIZE_ARB, &maxSparseTexSize);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d %d %d %d\n", width, height, depth, maxSparseTexSize);
    glTexStorage2D(
        /*target*/GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        /*levels*/1,
        /*internalFormat*/GL_R16UI,
        /*width*/maxSparseTexSize,
        /*height*/maxSparseTexSize);
    // commit one page at (0, 0, 0)
    glTexPageCommitmentARB(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        /*level*/0,
        /*xoffset*/0,
        /*yoffset*/0,
        /*zoffset*/0,
        /*width*/width,
        /*height*/height,
        /*depth*/depth,
        /*commit*/GL_TRUE);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Am I missing *anything* here or is it just a driver or GLFW bug?

EDIT: Some more information:
The crash happens in a driver thread (nvoglv64.dll) right after the main thread called `wglDeleteContext(...)` for the GL context. When the Visual Studio 2019 debugger halts due to the exception, I can see three driver threads (all from nvoglv64.dll) existing (one of which issued the access violation exception) while the main thread is halted right after `wglDeleteContext(...)`.

EDIT2: Experimenting more with this, the crash always occurred when the texture was not dereferenced (ref count to 0) and disposed of by the driver before destroying the GL context. For example, in the code above, when I call  `glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);` right before `glDestroyWindow(window)`, the crash does not occur (reproducibly). In the actual app I distilled the above MCVE from, the texture was also attached as a color attachment in a FBO. When I did *not* deleted the FBO but only decremented the ref count for the texture (by calling `glDeleteTextures(...)`, the crash would still occur. Only when I also dereferenced the FBO by `glDeleteFramebuffers(...)` and the texture along with it, would the crash not occur anymore.

Comment: Did you try a texture of less than `maxSparseTexSize`?

Comment: @YakovGalka Yes, 2048 and 1024, same issue.

Comment: Suggestions: try with a Debug build of GLFW etc, try with a stable WHQL NVIDIA driver version, try doing the low-level calls yourself, etc.

Comment: @Acorn thanks, yeah, I just tried with a GLFW Debug build and Debug build of the MCVE app, same issue. I will downgrade the driver. I also uninstalled GeForce Experience (which seems to have been installed alongside the driver) to avoid any interception/injection of GL/driver calls for overlays etc., but same issue after uninstalling that.

Comment: I've also debugged through GLFW, and `glfwDestroyWindow()` is _literally_ only calling `wglDeleteContext(window->context.wgl.handle);` until the crash happens. There is no other platform call between that. I am quite certain it's not a GLFW bug, as this is the first time _ever_ I've seen this crash happen in hundreds of applications (btw. the original app was a Java/LWJGL app, which I ported and distilled to the C example above). I'll try with GLUT first, before descending into Win API and WGL calls, but I suspect the crash to happen there as well.

Comment: I'm about to dismiss this as a Windows Nvidia driver bug after all. I've compiled the same MCVE as above on Ubuntu 20.10 with Nvidia 450.102.04 and the issue doesn't happen there.

Comment: Interestingly, when I `glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);` right before `glDestroyWindow(window)`, everything works fine. I'll roll with that then.